# Find position of part of a INSERT statement in a string

Tags: php, mysql, preg-match-all

I am trying to find the string positions after the word "VALUES" in INSERT statement, this would be the position before the actual row data.

I know I need to use regular expression to pick up the pattern for INSERT statements and not use strpos to look for the word "VALUES", but when is comes to regular expression functions I'm a bit of a novice.

**UPDATED**

I would like to find the position of ") VALUES (" and allowing whitespaces, \n, \r, \t etc between the parentheses as sometimes VALUES is on a new line.

Thanks

SQL file:

```sql
# ------------------------------

# --
# -- Dumping data for table `table_a`
# --

INSERT INTO `table_a` (`a`, `b`, `c`, `d`) 
VALUES -- get position 
(1, 'b', 'c', 'd'),
(2, 'b', 'c', 'd'),
(3, 'b', 'c', 'd');

# ------------------------------

# --
# -- Dumping data for table `table_b`
# --

INSERT INTO `table_b` (`a`, `b`, `c`, `d`) VALUES -- get position 
(1, 'b', 'c', 'd'),
(2, 'b', 'c', 'd'),
(3, 'b', 'c', 'd');
```

Comment: What do you want the result to be?

Comment: I really hope you're not trying to parse SQL with regular expressions.

Comment: What would be the problem with just using `strpos()` to look for `VALUES`? The only other case where I can think `VALUES` would be present would be in an `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` clause in an insert. If you don;t have any of those, which I can't think of why you would in a table dump, there shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @BackinaFlash I would like the result to be an array of the positions.

Comment: @MikeBrant using strpos would cause a problem if a table field contains the word "VALUES in it". e.g. INSERT INTO `table_b` (`a`, `VALUES OF MINE`, `c`, `d`) VALUES...

Comment: Then find `VALUES[\s\n\r]\(`

Comment: @arbme Then search for `) VALUES`.

Comment: @arbme Don't get me wrong, normally something like this is a bad idea, (trying to use regex or strpos on data that is not necessarily that ordered) but if you have a limited use case where you have an understanding of what the data is going to be, that could be quick and dirty way to get what you need.

Comment: @MikeBrant Could I not use reg ex to look for ") VALUES (" allowing spaces, \n, \r, \t etc between the parentheses. I only ask as ") VALUES." wont work with my example as "VALUES" is on a new line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
$content = file_get_contents('/path/to/dump.sql');
$pattern = '/\)\s+VALUES\s+\(/U';
$matches = array();
$match_count = preg_match_all($pattern, $content, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);

// trim off the parenthesis and whitespace from each match and add length of remaining portion of match string to the match offset to get offset at end of 'VALUES'
$offsets = array();
foreach($matches[0] as $match) {
    $offsets[] = $match[1] + strlen(rtrim(substr($match[0], 0, -1)));
}
```

Comment: Great reg ex thanks, need to edit $matches to $matches[0] in foreach() to make it work. Thanks

Comment: What does "/U" do exactly in the regular expression?

Comment: @arbme `U` is a pattern modifier that makes the match ungreedy, such that it matches the smallest possible string.  It is probably not actually needed in this case since the only classes you are matching against are whitespace.  If however the pattern was `/\).*VALUES.*\(/` You could be matching almost your entire filesbetween the first `VALUES` and the last `(` if the pattern used its default greedy behavior.  You can use that pattern with and without the `U` to see the difference yourself. Link with more info on pattern modifiers: http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php